# Integral of function with absolute value

Tags: integration, absolute-value

Let us consider the following integral for $x>0$

$$\int_{-1}^x e^{|t|} \, dt=\int_{-1}^0 e^{-t}dt+\int_0^1 e^t dt=e^x+e-2.$$

If we take $\frac{d}{dt}|t|=\mathrm{sgn}(t)$ we might want to evaluate it as

$$\int_{-1}^x e^{|t|} dt =\biggr[\frac{e^{|t|}}{\mathrm{sgn}(t)} \biggr]^x_{-1}=e^x+e.$$

My question is: why doesn't the second method work? Why is there a $-2$ missing? It looks strange too, since the integral is not a continuous function of $x$ either.

Comment: In the second integral, you didn't take into account $\text{sgn}(t)$ while integrating and directly took out of the integration and applied limits. When you take that into account it will again split into two integrals giving you the same answer.

Comment: @sudeep5221 i don't quite see that you mean by that

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you evaluated the second integral? Maybe it'll be easier for me to help you with it then. Did you use something like integration by parts?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of failure in the method of substitutions. You can only substitute for functions that do not change sign over the interval of the integral. $|t|$ and consequently its derivative $sgn(t)$ do not hold the same sign over $[-1, x]$.